# Has anyone ever conducted a psychological experiment to test whether an arbitrator appointed by one party tends to judge in favour of that party?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, experimental-psychology, decision-making, bias

I am interested in the case where the arbitrator has been unilaterally appointed by one of the parties in a conflict. Assume that economic rewards are not involved. I am only interested in knowing if being appointed by one of the parties to the dispute tends to make arbitrators side with the party who selected them, or at least be more favourable to their cause.